# Why is my CSS not working and Div's collapsing?

Tags: css, html

I think I must be having a Friday moment, but why are my DIV's all collapsing and the styles not taking effect on the following link http://s374335087.websitehome.co.uk/help.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a CSS class name can start with a number.